# How to validate checkboxes on submit button?

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox

I have a simply question but I try many things but they not working as I expect.

Problem:
1. A few checkboxes with class like "a" ,"b" ,"c" but with different id's.
2. On button click I try to validate that only one of checkboxes is checked.
3. I know only checkbox classes(The common element)

My code:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var matches = [];
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('1'); //??? if the items is null?

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        matches.push({id:items[i].id, value:items[i].value});
    }

    if((matches[0].id != matches[1].id) &&(matches[0].value == matches[1].value))
        alert("ERROR!!!");
});
```

Please show me the best way to resolve that problem

Comment: can you update your question with some sample html?

Comment: "On button click I try to validate that only one of checkboxes is checked" — Why are you using checkboxes instead of radio buttons in the first place?

Comment: Because I must @ Quentin

Comment: you mean on form submit, not button click right.....

Comment: Button Click. @  Popnoodles

Comment: Why are you doing that instead of on form submit? There's often more than one way to submit a form.

Comment: Your question title states "validate checkboxes **on submit** button?" Do you mean on click of submit button?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName('1');` classnames should not begin with numbers http://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/822711 Also since you're using jQuery what's wrong with selecting them using jQuery?

Comment: Thank's for this tip guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using jQuery. You want to use checkboxes with classname "1" almost as if they were radio buttons, and alert an error if more than one is checked. Your [classname is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/822711), and most likely you should be checking this on form submit instead, but here's the code you're looking for.

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    if ($('.1:checked').length > 1) alert('error');
});
```

...And I imagine you would also want to stop the button from submitting the form in that case:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
    if ($('.1:checked').length > 1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Working very well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
See this code it may be help you!
```

```
<input type = "checkbox" class = "a ownClass" id = "one"></input>
<input type = "checkbox" class = "b ownClass" id = "two"></input>
<input type = "checkbox" class = "c ownClass" id = "three"></input>
<input type = "button" id = "submit" value = "submit"></input>


  (function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
        var checked = [];
        $(".ownClass").each(function(currIndex, val){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            checked.push(this.id);
        }

     })
    console.log(checked);
  });
}());
```

Comment: Thanks. But in my case @Popnoodles anserw is the best one :D